# Ошибка при подключении базы данных через Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Добавил в gradle проект `runtimeOnly mysql:mysql-connector-java`
и
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

И теперь после сборки выдаёт следующие ошибки :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

**Вот код:**

```
package com.example.MySpringFrame;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringFrameApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringFrameApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.MySpringFrame.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity getUsers(){
        try{
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Сервер работает!");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return  ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    }
}
```

**и мой `application.properties`:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_base?useUnicode=true&useSSL=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Указанная база данных создана но выдаёт данную ошибку и я не понимаю почему.

Comment: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect - добавьте в проперти

Comment: [org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26548505/312041) там только БД другая

Answer (score 0):

Тут уже намекнули, что надо добавить в `application.properties` следующую строку

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Собственно это свойство Hibernate `hibernate.dilect`, можно выбрать из пакета для соответствующей базы данных.

В gradle надо писать:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}
```